# Residue of a function with (essential) singularities at both $0$ and $\infty$

Tags: residue-calculus

I need to take the residue of the following function at infinity:
$$
f(z) = \oint_\infty \left(\frac{e^{-\alpha/z}e^{-\alpha z}}{z}\right)dz
$$
Which, up to a sign, is invariant under inversions $z\rightarrow 1/w$, since $dz \rightarrow -\frac{1}{w^2} dw$.

How can I proceed to take a Laurent expansion of this function at $z = \infty$ (or $z = 0$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around $z = 0$, the exponential is the generating function for the [Modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), e.g.
$$
e^{\frac{t}{2}(z + 1/z)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty I_n(t)z^n.
$$

Thus, we find

$$
f(z) = \oint_\infty \left(\frac{e^{-\alpha/z}e^{-\alpha z}}{z}\right)dz = \oint_\infty \frac{dz}{z}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty I_n(2\alpha)z^n = I_0(2\alpha).
$$
Which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have $e^{-\frac \alpha z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac \alpha z\right)^n$, so
$$\frac{e^{-\frac \alpha z}}{z}=\frac1z-\frac \alpha{z^2}+\cdots.$$
Also $\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-\alpha z}=1$, hence
$$\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{-\frac \alpha z}e^{-\alpha z}}{z}=1.$$
If you want to calculate the residue at $\infty$ directly, you may expand $e^{-\alpha z}$ and you will get the same answer.

Comment: This is incorrect I believe, I have posted the correct answer.